# How can i order products array by id

Tags: java, arrays

i hope you can help me i am trying to order these arrays

```
int pumpno[] = new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6};
String desc[] = new String[] {"jam", "chesse", "milk", "water",   "soup","bread"};
int cost[] = new int[] {10, 15, 23, 43, 12, 67};
```

I want to print in these order:

```
id   3 
----------
desc jam

cost 10

desc water

cost 43

id   4
----------
desc chesse

cost 15

desc soup

cost 12


id   5 
----------
desc milk

cost 23

id   6
----------
desc bread

cost 63
```

For example each array has the same lenght in this case is 9, in the firts array theare numbers with the same value for the id so, i just want to print once time the value for id and print all de values below with the same id

i just have make how to know if is equal id  i make it with these

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < pumpno.length; i++) {
if (set.contains(pumpno[i])) {
    Log.d("Duplicate ", pumpno[i]);
} else {
    set.add(pumpno[i]);
}
```

But i have no idea how to print like the example above. if you can help me thanks a lot

Comment: Rory McCrossan thanks for edit my question i am learning how to use this great space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HashMap` which has id as key and `Set<Product>` as values (if you want not to have duplicates or list if you want order of products). You can fill it up in one iteration and print in another.

Product would be data structure which has description and price.

```
Map<int, Set<Product>> productsById = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < pumpno.length; i++) {
    if (productsById.containsKey(pumpno[i])) {
      //add product to existing set
      productsById.get(pumpno[i]).add(new Product(desc[i], cost[i]));
    } else {
        //create set since this is first time id is shown
        Set<Product> set = new HashSet<Product>();
        set.add(new Product(desc[i], cost[i]);
        productsById.put(pumpno[i], set);
    }
}

String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
for (int id : productsById.keySet()){
   System.out.println("id " + id + newLine);
   for (Product product : productsById.get(id)){
     System.out.println("description" + product.getDescription() + newLine);
     System.out.println("cost" + product.getCost() + newLine);   
   }
}
```

Hope I did not make mistakes since I typed here in markdown but that is logic.

Comment: Ok, i am really new as programmer let me try, to implement this example Thanks Nenad

Comment: I can add Product class if you need it, can you handle that, and can you add printing or you need that as well?

Comment: No, thanks Nenad let try by myself i want to learn, i think i understand your solution now if i have problems with that i hope you can help me.

Comment: If you manage to apply it accept solution and if not ask what is not clear and I will try to help you out.

Comment: Works exactly as i want, thank you very much :) your help was amazing.